# SVG only one path animate

Tags: svg, css-animations

How can I animate the opacity only of the #path1, and not #path2 in the below clip-path.

```css
#path1 {
  animation: fadeInAnimation ease 5s;
}

@keyframes fadeInAnimation {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg class="svg-path" viewBox="0 0 643 525">
  
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="shape">
      <path id="path1" d="M0 0 v100 h35 c0,0, 7,15, 15,0 h35 v-45 c0,0, -20,-7, 0,-15 v-45 Z"/>
      <path id="path2" d="M100 0 v100 h35 c0,0, 7,15, 15,0 h35 v-45 c0,0, -20,-7, 0,-15 v-45 Z"/>

    </clipPath>
    
  </defs>
<image width="643" height="643" clip-path="url(#shape)"  xlink:href="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/222579/beagle400.jpg" >
</image>

</svg>
```

The above code does not animate neither path1 nor path2

Comment: In your code the paths are not visible since you have them both inside <clipPath>. Maybe you want to animate the <image>

Comment: The contents of the clipPath are only used as for their raw geometry so opacity, fill, stroke etc don't apply to them. I expect you want a mask rather than a clipPath here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like commented the clip-path could be replaced by a mask. The mask will show areas that are not black. So, here I gave #path1 and #path2 a white fill and then the animation shows when #path1 turns more and more white.

```css
#path1 {
  animation: fadeInAnimation ease 5s;
}

@keyframes fadeInAnimation {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg class="svg-path" viewBox="0 0 643 525">
  <defs>
    <mask id="shape">
      <path id="path1" d="M0 0 v100 h35 c0,0, 7,15, 15,0 h35 v-45 c0,0, -20,-7, 0,-15 v-45 Z" 
        fill="white"/>
      <path id="path2" d="M100 0 v100 h35 c0,0, 7,15, 15,0 h35 v-45 c0,0, -20,-7, 0,-15 v-45 Z"
        fill="white"/>
    </mask>
  </defs>
  <image width="643" height="643" mask="url(#shape)"
    href="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/222579/beagle400.jpg" />
</svg>
```

Comment: Thank you all very much. This is indeed what I was searching for. Could I kindly ask you chrwahl why is the image to the left appearing all of a sudden after 5s and does not allow for a smooth fade in?  I tried both on Edge and Chrome and it does not work. If this is not linked with the topic I can open another question. When I change in the css the #path1 with the .svg-path meaning if I apply the animation to the svg then I get the smooth fade in effect, but not on #path1.